# How to read data set in first VC in other VC?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults

I am a looking for a way to read the data set in the first view controller in another view controller

In my fist VC i have

```
class ScannerViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    var scannedVisitors = [Visitor]()

.....
....
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // test data, will be provided server side
        var visitor = Visitor(visitorName: "John", visitorCompany: "google", visitorPlace: "San", visitorPhone: "94888484", visitorEmail: "john@google.com")
        scannedVisitors += [visitor]

visitor = Visitor(visitorName: "Matt", visitorCompany: "apple", visitorPlace: "Tokyo", visitorPhone: "94888484", visitorEmail: "matt@apple.com")
        scannedVisitors += [visitor]
```

Now First view in Storyboard shows the scannedVisitors

But in an other viewController/view i like to list all scannedVisitors in a table view again, for this i have

```
class ListVisitorsVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var scannedVisitorsArr = [Visitor]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // first try this, later use NSUserDefaults or Core Data 
        let firstVC = ScannerViewController()
        scannedVisitorsArr = firstVC.scannedVisitors
        print("Visitors \(scannedVisitorsArr)")

    }
```

But the scannnedVisitorsArr is empty???

1/ How can i fix the empty scannedVisitorsArr? Should i have a seperate populate scannedVisitors function in my first view controller??

2/ Is there a size restriction when using NSUserDefaults??

[EDIT]
Testing with adding a function to first VC

```
    func readAndPopulateData(){
  var visitor = Visitor(visitorName: "John", visitorCompany: "google", visitorPlace: "San", visitorPhone: "94888484", visitorEmail: "john@google.com")
            scannedVisitors += [visitor]

    visitor = Visitor(visitorName: "Matt", visitorCompany: "apple", visitorPlace: "Tokyo", visitorPhone: "94888484", visitorEmail: "matt@apple.com")
            scannedVisitors += [visitor]
    }
```

and

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
self.readAndPopulateData()
```

Now in my other VC

```
let firstVC = ScannerViewController()
        firstVC.readAndPopulateData()
        scannedVisitorsArr = firstVC.scannedVisitors
```

But this just returns

```
Visitors [folder_name.Visitor, folder_name.Visitor]
```

and not the data set?

[EDIT]
Reading up on data container singleton as it looks like it's usable for this. But i read different pos/neg stories about using singletons? Any tips on the subject data container singleton are welcome.

Comment: don't use NSUserDefaults for this purpose, that's not what it is for. To read that data set, either pass it to your next VC when you segue OR use navigation controller viewcontrollers array to access last VC, from their access the data set

Comment: it's empty because ScannerViewController doesn't run into viewDidLoad method. If you set breakpoint in this , you will see

Comment: "pass it to your next VC when you segue ", but in my case it's the "second" segue. First i have a segue to a detail view and here i have a button which goes to a table list view. (= this can't be the same as the first VC as the first VC has more UI elements besides a table view). 
Could you give me some code examples for nextVC segue and navigation controller viewcontrollers array ?

Comment: @CongTran could i fix this by putting the code in viewDidAppear or something like that?? i thought of it like it was some sort of global variable being populated as soon as the app starts

Comment: Where you navigate to OtherViewController?

Comment: @Irfan, i navigate to OtherViewController from a table detail view. So my first VC has 2 UI elements (one camera layer + one table view) -> click on a table row shows table detail view (which has a button going to OtherViewController)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use prepareForSegue Method

example

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "ToListVisitorsVC") {
      //Checking identifier is crucial as there might be multiple
      // segues attached to same view
      var detailVC = segue!.destinationViewController as ListVisitorsVC;
      detailVC.visitors = self.scannedVisitors
    }
}
```

Comment: problem in my case is scannedVisitors is not "set" in table detail view? and self.scannedVisitors should be something like firstVC.scannedVisitors, i think

Comment: than you need to create delegate .... declare a protocol in first VC and implement that also in firstVC and call this function from where you need this array ....

Comment: could you provide a simple code example " create delegate and declare protocol" part???

Comment: you can get very good amount of Swift example ... on internet